# Ruby regex to match double mustache but not triple mustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, mustache

I am using mustache gem in my ruby on rails app. Given a template, I would like to replace all double mustache in the template with triple mustache, and not replace when it is a triple mustache.  There won't be single mustache in the original template, so i don't want to worry about single mustache.

Eg:

```
temp = "You have just won {{value}} {{{currency}}}!"
```

should convert to

```
temp = "You have just won {{{value}}} {{{currency}}}!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done via a negative lookahead.

```regex
\{\{[^}]+\}\}(?!\})
```

This will match substrings enclosed by 2 mustaches, but not followed by a third.

The matches can then be enclosed with extra mustaches.

```ruby
temp = "You have just won {{value}} {{{currency}}}!"
temp.gsub!(/\{\{[^}]+\}\}(?!\})/, '{\&}')
puts temp
```